# Referencing partial in sub folder with Spark

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, spark-view-engine

Apparently you can reference a partial with Spark view engine as a tag with the same name as the partial e.g: `<myPartialName />` instead of using `<render partial="myPartialName" />`

That is great, but how do you reference the partial if it is in a sub folder? e.g. `<render partial="partials/myPartialName" />`

Anyone know if there is a way to deal with this?

**UPDATE**

After reading the documentation on organising content, I saw the following paragraph which explained why the above was not working:

> Implicit partial rendering
>
> Finally, if your partial file starts with an underscore character the
>   rest of the file name can be used as a new special element. This is
>   nothing more than  being used as a shortcut for but it
>   sure looks cool.

I.e. you must append an underscore to a partial name if you want to use implicit rendering, as mentioned in the answer by lomaxx below. So to use the tag `<myPartialName/>` the actual partial file would have to be `_myPartialName.spark`.

Comment: What's the error you're getting when trying to use the partials?

Comment: There was no error, it was simply not rendering, however, I just read the documentation and understand what you were saying in your answer below, see my edit on the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that if you have a partial named _myPartialName (note the underscore) in your subfolder, then you need to reference the name explicitly as the shortcuts don't handle the underscore in subfolders properly. So you need to explicitly include the underscore like so:

```
<render partial="partials/_myPartialName" />
```

Or you can just change the partial name and remove the underscore

Comment: hi again, you seem to be answering all my spark related questions :D, I think you misunderstood what I am asking. Writing <myPartialName /> is equivalent to <render partial="myPartialName"/>, however I keep partials in a sub-folder so what is the equivalent of <render partial="partials/myPartialName"/> e.g. <partials:mypartialname /> or something simillar?